# Extract data from geographic information system (GIS) layer with the "pulldata @layer" function

Tags: arcgis-pro

My objective is to extract the name of the road closest to the point collected previously (geopoint) in the previous question, and return it automatically to the following field, knowing that the road layer hosted in our organization's server.
I work on Survey123 connect.

Comment: Asking duplicate questions isn't the way to avoid closure https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478651/extract-data-from-a-geographic-information-system-gis-layer-with-the-pulldata